# Count unique values within model's Array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the best way to just COUNT unique values within many model's array? Let's say my Model is like this:

```
{
  myKey: [
    "idnumber1000",
    "idnumber1001",
    "idnumber1005",
  ]
}
```

And that I have about 10.000 of them, but with different values for `myKey`. I want to know, how many DIFFERENT values I have for a given set of collection.

My initial idea was to load ALL models in memory, and then, compute that with Node.js. But as my data set can grow a lot (about 30-50K), that would consume a lot of memory in my machine. Is this the only way to doit, or is there another?

I'm using Mongoose with Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `aggregate` pipeline:

```
MyModel.aggregate([
    // Project just the myKey field as that's all that's needed
    {$project: {_id: 0, myKey: 1}},
    // Duplicate each doc, once per myKey element
    {$unwind: '$myKey'},
    // Group on myKey and get a count
    {$group: {_id: '$myKey', count: {$sum: 1}}}
  ],
  function(err, results) {...}
);
```